# Division z / (x/n) when n is 0

Tags: c++

I have an arithmetic expression, for example:

```
float z = 8.0
float x = 3.0;
float n = 0;
cout << z / (x/n) + 1 << endl;
```

Why I get normal answer equal to 1, when it should be "nan", "1.#inf", etc.?

Comment: -1 for not specifying the types of your variables.

Comment: @Maciej: I'd call that edit "vandalism". If the OP actually has integral variables, the answer is totally different, and we really don't know. Roll back maybe?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Look on the diff. He wrote that "Variables are float." - all I have done was putting it in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're using floating point arithmetic (though one can't be sure, because you're not telling us).

IEEE754  floating point semantics work on the extended real line and include infinities on both ends. This makes divisions with non-zero numerator well-defined for *any* (non-NaN) denominator, "consistent with" (i.e. extending continuously) the usual arithmetic rules: `x / n` is infinity, and `z` divided by infinity is zero — just as if you had simplified the expression as `n * z / x`.

The only genuinely undefined quantities are 0/0 and inf/inf, which are represented by the special value NaN.

Comment: “consistent with the usual arithmetic rules” – no. The *usual* arithmetic rules forbid division by 0. You can get around that, but those are not the usual rules. And by the usual rules you also cannot rewrite the expression in the way you suggested – in fact, [it’s a classical fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy#All_numbers_equal_all_other_numbers).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I should have said "constitutes a continuous extension of the usual arithmetic rules, in a suitable topology" (namely the standard two-point compactification of the reals).

Answer (score 2):

The IEEE 754 specifies that `3/0 = Inf` (or anything positive instead of 3).  `8/Inf` gives 0.  If you add 1 you'll receive 1. This is because `0` denotes "0 or something very close to it" and `Inf` "Infinity or very big number". It also allows to perform some operations on limits as it effectively extends the real numbers into by infinities. `NaN`'s are reserved when the limit is not achievable (or not easily computable by simple implementation).

As a side effect you have some strange effects like `0 == -0` but `1/0 == Inf` and `1/-0 == -Inf`. It is important to remember that FP arithmetic is not normal - for example `cos(x) * cos(x) + sin(x) * sin(x) - 1 != 0` even if `x != NaN && x != Inf && x != -Inf`. For floats and `x == 1` the result is `-5.9604645e-8`. Therefore not all expectation can be easily transferred to it - like division by 0 in this case.

While C/C++ does not mandate that IEE 754 specification will be used for floating point numbers it is the specification right now and is implemented on virtually any hardware and for that reason used by most C/C++ implementations.

Comment: @hvd You mean x86, the platform that has had IEEE 754 arithmetic since 2001, or do you mean another x86? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka In my comments, I treated IEEE 754 as a whole, and that was misleading. Effectively, an extended precision format is a non-standard format using the standard (IEEE) rules for rounding etc. I focused far too much on the former while your comment is really about the latter.

Comment: @hvd Summing up the deleted thread - 80 bit FP implemented in x87 were extended precision format. IEEE 754 don't specifies the details (format etc.) they are in specification. Most compilers allow them by `long double`. From PIII the 'normal' SP FP were introduced (and in P IV DP) so the need for using x87 is limited to backward compatibility with older processors.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Yes, agreed.